# Firefox not respecting outer block max-width for inner inline element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/6dqjoLrn/2/

I am making a custom input box, which would contain a variety of ContentEditable SPANs and some non-ContentEditable DIVs.  I am trying to contain all of the ContentEditable SPANs inside the bounds of my 'input box'.  All of these elements are inside a DIV with a set max-width, which I would expect would be able to contain all of the elements.  This is the case for Chrome and IE, but does not seem to be working in Firefox (which can be seen by running the Fiddle).  Is there something I am doing wrong when trying to contain these, or is there some special trick I need in Firefox to make this happen?

Thanks.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Outside">
    <div class="tokenizer">
        <div class="content">
            <span contenteditable="true" class="textInput lastInput empty"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="dropdownbtn" class="listHidden">&#x25BC;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    font-size: 16px;
}

span {
    border: 0px;
}

span.textInput {
    line-height:29px;
    word-break: break-all;
}

span:focus {
    outline: none;
}

span.empty {
    width: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tokenizer {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: text;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    max-width: 474px;
}

#dropdownbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid #39668D;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E0E9F1;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #39668D;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#Outside {
    top:40px;
    left:50px;
    width:100%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('span.textInput').on('keydown', function(event) {

    var element = $(event.target);
    if (element.text().length > 0) {
        if (element.hasClass('empty')) {
            element.removeClass('empty');
        }
    } else {
        if (!element.hasClass('empty')) {
            element.addClass('empty');
        }
    }
});

$('.tokenizer').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($('.curInput').length) {
        $('.curInput').focus();
    } else {
        $('.lastInput').focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS.

```css
.content {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

`word-break: break-word;` should also work.

That solved the problem for me. http://jsfiddle.net/5de1zq8n/

Both Chrome and Firefox appear were using the default style `word-break: normal;` but Chrome seems to obey the `max-width`, while Firefox doesn't.

Hope that helps.